# How to sum a df while ignoring value in R?

Tags: r

This is an extension of [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62769556/how-to-collapse-table-while-ignore-a-specific-value-in-r). I reviewed the linked duplicate, but I am still having trouble.

I have a data frame like the following:

```
> example
  name X1.8 X1.8.1 X1.8.2
1    a   -1      1      7
2    b   33      0      2
3    c    3     10     -1
4    a   -1     -1      4
5    d    5      8      5
6    e    7      6     12
7    a   -1      7      7
8    c    5     20      9
9    f   -1     -1     -1
```

and I want to collapse(sum) the row with the same name (column 1) but ignore the value `-1` while collapsing (summing). *-1 is similar to NA. For example, the example above would become:

```
> example    # the goal
  name X1.8 X1.8.1 X1.8.2
1    a   -1      8      18 # the first col stays as -1 b/c all are -1
2    b   33      0       2
3    c    8     30       9
4    d    5      8       5
5    e    7      6      12
6    f   -1     -1      -1

> dput(example)
structure(list(name = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
3L, 6L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), class = "factor"), 
    X1.8 = c(-1, 33, 3, -1, 5, 7, -1, 5, -1), X1.8.1 = c(1, 0, 
    10, -1, 8, 6, 7, 20, -1), X1.8.2 = c(7, 2, -1, 4, 5, 12, 
    7, 9, -1)), row.names = c(NA, 9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use an `if/else` after doing the `group_by` i.e. after grouping by 'name', `summarise` `across` all the other columns (`dplyr` 1.0.0), `if` `all` values are `-1`, then return it or `else` get the `sum` of values excluding -1

```
library(dplyr) # 1.0.0
example %>%
   group_by(name) %>%
   summarise(across(everything(), ~ if(all(.==-1)) -1 else
            sum(.[. != -1], na.rm = TRUE)))
# A tibble: 6 x 4
#  name   X1.8 X1.8.1 X1.8.2
#  <fct> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 a        -1      8     18
#2 b        33      0      2
#3 c         8     30      9
#4 d         5      8      5
#5 e         7      6     12
#6 f        -1     -1     -1
```

An option is also to use `na_if` to replace the `-1` to `NA` and then make use of `na.rm= TRUE` in `sum`.  But, we have avoided that route in case there are actual `NA`s in the dataset for a particular group.  This would help in identifying the `-1` as such

---

or with `summarise_at`

```
example %>%
   group_by(name) %>%
   summarise_at(vars(-group_cols()), ~ if(all(.==-1)) -1 else
           sum(.[. != -1], na.rm = TRUE))
# A tibble: 6 x 4
#  name   X1.8 X1.8.1 X1.8.2
#  <fct> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 a        -1      8     18
#2 b        33      0      2
#3 c         8     30      9
#4 d         5      8      5
#5 e         7      6     12
#6 f        -1     -1     -1
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution could help you:

```
library(dplyr)
#Format
example[example==-1]<-NA
#Aggregate
example %>% group_by(name) %>% summarise_all(sum,na.rm=T)

# A tibble: 6 x 4
  name   X1.8 X1.8.1 X1.8.2
  <fct> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 a         0      8     18
2 b        33      0      2
3 c         8     30      9
4 d         5      8      5
5 e         7      6     12
6 f         0      0      0
```

Comment: this is great ! but I would like to keep `-1` because it indicates NA values; here, you have changes to 0

Answer (score 0):

base R

```
aggregate(x = example[,2:4],
          by = list(name = example$name),
          FUN = function(x)ifelse(all(x==-1), -1, sum(x[x!=-1])))
```